# Why is my SQL Server Update stored procedure not updating my gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sql-update

I am very new to C# so please be nice. I am doing a project where I want to create a gridview that will display records that you can search through, insert, update, cancel, and edit. The search, cancel, and edit buttons have been completed. Right now, I am struggling with the update.

I created a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_sp_Update]
    @UserNumId int, 
    @UserName nvarchar,
    @UserNumber nvarchar,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE USER_NUMBERS 
    SET UserName = @UserName, 
        UserNumber = @UserNumber, 
        StartDate = @StartDate,
        EndDate =  @EndDate
    WHERE UserNumId = @UserNumId
END
```

Then, I created an update functionality that is not working. I click the update button, and what happens is the record is missing characters in the database, and it isn't really updated at all.

I have been doing hours long research, and I have no idea what to do.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd_update = new SqlCommand("_sp_Update", con);
            cmd_update.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserNumId", (GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
            cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserNumber", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserNumber") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
            cmd_update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

            cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            PopulateGridview();

            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
        lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

******* I UPDATED THE CODE TO THIS - NOW NOTHING UPDATES AND I RECEIVE THIS ERROR MESSAGE - Object must implement IConvertible.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

        {

            con.Open();

            Label UserNumID = 
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_UserNumID") as Label;
            TextBox UserName = 
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserName") as TextBox;
            TextBox UserNumber = 
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUserNumber") as TextBox;
            TextBox StartDate = 
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox EndDate = 
 GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;

            SqlCommand cmd_update = new SqlCommand("_sp_Update", con);
            cmd_update.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd_update.Parameters.Add("@UserNumId", 
SqlDbType.Int).Value=UserNumID;
            cmd_update.Parameters.Add("@UserName", 
SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=UserName;
            cmd_update.Parameters.Add("@UserNumber", 
SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=UserNumber;
            cmd_update.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", 
SqlDbType.Date).Value=StartDate;
            cmd_update.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", 
 SqlDbType.Date).Value=EndDate;

            cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery();


            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            PopulateGridview();

            con.Close();

    }

        }
}
```

Comment: Why should it? You execute an SP and then call some mystic "PopulateGridView" method which we do not know - there is nothing about reading data.

Comment: Nothing about that SP will `DELETE` the row. All the details might change, which might mean that a previous search criteria doesn't match the row, but otherwise what you are saying certainly does not happen.

Comment: I'm sorry. I know many of you are going to be way more experienced than me so please be nice. I have been trying to do this on my own. I have watched many videos, and I have read many articles and tried to follow the steps. And I am failing miserably...... I have been following this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuoJeQ4L3WI

Comment: PopulateGridview(); is a function I created above...                                                          void PopulateGridview()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM USER_NUMBERS WHERE EndDate is NULL ORDER BY UserNumID ASC", con);
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

Comment: Larnu, I know what I am saying seems ridiculous, but it is definitely deleting it. I click on the edit button. It is then in edit mode. Then, when I click update, the record disappears from the website and my SQL database.

Comment: **** UPDATE: Okay, Larnu, you are right. The record changed completely. It is in the database still, but it changed with values that I did not even input. I guess something is up with my parameters. Again, I am VERY new to this, and I am playing around with things.

Comment: Avoid using `AddWithValue`. It tries to imply SQL data types for parameters based on the .NET type of the values you pass in and often gets it wrong. e.g.: How will it figure out that the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters should be `date` when you pass in `string` types?

Comment: AlwaysLearning, thank you for your response. I did research on this as well - wondering if it that was the issue.  I tried using just Parameters.Add ("@UserNumber", UserNumber) & then set the variable UserNumber above it. Still it doesn't work. Or even  cmd_update.Parameters.Add ("@UserNumber", SqlDbType.Int);

Comment: *"but it changed with values that I did not even input"* I doubt that either, @Kiki , it's likely, however that what you *think* the parameter value are, they are not. Debugging with breakpoints is going to *really* help you here.

Comment: @Larnu          Thank you! I will look into this more and give updates later.

Comment: Okay, I tried a combination of what AlwaysLearning & @Larnu recommended. Now, nothing updates at all and I receive the following error message - "Object must implement IConvertible". I will post my new syntax above.